# Responsive height of images on resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm really stuck with responsive images short story I'm trying to make a simple grid like this

https://avenue-demo.squarespace.com

in this avenue website all the images have the same height and width when you resize the browser the images are resizing fine now here is my code

```
 <ul class="grid">
      <li>
           <a href="">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546725923-697533ae284d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" alt="">
           </a>
      </li>
      <li>
           <a href="">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546934164-73ef3631f62d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=933&q=80" alt="">
           </a>
      </li>
      <li>
           <a href="">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547014751-2b43a527b6fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" alt="">
           </a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

css :

```
.grid {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1100px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
}
.grid li {
    width: 30%;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

the problem is the images are not the same height when I set the height of the img to height 100% yes the images do have the same height but on resize they are shrinking not resizing like this website I posted, how can I fix it ?

Comment: The website you have mentioned uses only images of same size

Comment: so I do have to define the height of my images explicitly ?

Comment: The best method for this is to set the images as `<a>`'s background, then in CSS : `background-size:cover; background-position: center;`

Comment: Sorry for my mistake when I look into the website it seems like they are using javascript to resize the image. And the images are of not same size they are just hiding the by using overflow hidden in the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you need to have square images to get the shown responsiveness, even though i have made some css changes to your code, to look like the images from website (which is not suggested always)
here is the code pen link
https://codepen.io/avreddy/pen/vvabbP

```css
.grid {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1100px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
}
.grid li {
    width: 30%;
}
.grid li a{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50% 0;
  display : block;
}
.grid li a img{
  position: absolute;
  width : 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit : cover;
  
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
      <li>
           <a href="">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546725923-697533ae284d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" alt="">
           </a>
      </li>
      <li>
           <a href="">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546934164-73ef3631f62d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=933&q=80" alt="">
           </a>
      </li>
      <li>
           <a href="">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547014751-2b43a527b6fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" alt="">
           </a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve, will study your code thank you so much

Comment: The constraint is, all your images must be physically square. The `background-size:cover` technique (see my comment above) has no constraint and achieves a perfect cover no matter what.